# Check if a class variable is accessed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, class, variables, web

How can I check if "class" variable is being accessed in JavaScript?

**For example:**

```
function Class(){

    this.string = "foo";
    this.saySomething = saySomething;

    if(/*not accessing saySomething*/){
    return "empty";
    }

}

function saySomething(){

    alert(this.string);

}
```

So

```
alert(Class());
```

should alert "empty" and

```
alert(Class().saySomething())
```

should output "foo".

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing"?

Comment: I want to check if Class().saySomething() is being called or only Class().

Comment: @user3289949 _JavaScript_ is (mostly) synchronous. `Class().saySomething()` means `Class` is invoked, then when it has finished, the `return`ed object's `saySomething` property is invoked. Both don't happen "at the same time"

Comment: Exactly. When saySomething() is not being called the function should return a string rather then nothing.

Comment: Wait, so you mean.. you want to know if `Class` is being chained?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is to always return an _Object_, but setting it's `valueOf`

Comment: I added another example I hope it's a little bit clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is by using `toString` and then causing it to be invoked, for example

```
function Class() {
    this.string = 'foo';
}
Class.prototype.saySomething = function () {
    return this.string;
};
Class.prototype.toString = function () {
    return 'empty';
};
// and use
var c = new Class();
c + '';           // 'empty', or
alert(c);         // 'empty'
c.saySomething(); // 'foo'
```

Comment: You probably want .toString and not .valueOf but this sounds like what I'd go for.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Maybe, but then I thought, why not use both?

Comment: This still doesn't do what the OP requested, although you could do something similar that did. (Because you've added `new` and a prototype.)

Comment: @user3289949: While you *can* do this, the use cases for it are few and far between. That's why is suggested giving the broader scope.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP was asking using the word "Class" so I took a guess, you could set up the constructor with an `if (!(this instanceof Class)) return new Class();` though

Comment: @PaulS.: Or just have it return an object in the first place.

Comment: @PaulS. please consult the specification on the different between valueOf and toString. Mainly this http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8 in short - valueOf is for number conversion and toString is for string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> So
>
> `alert(Class());`
>
> should alert "empty" and
>
> `alert(Class().saySomething())`
>
> should output "foo".

You can't (reasonably) do that, because what happens in `Class().saySomething()` is that `Class()` is called and returns something, and then we (try to) call `saySomething()` on it. There's no way for the code in `Class` to know that it's being called as part of the overall expression `Class().saySomething()`. All it knows is that it's being called, it doesn't know what the code calling it is going to do with its return value.

You could always *tell* it, of course, by passing in an argument, but I suspect if you ask a new question describing the broader goal you're trying to accomplish, we can help you accomplish it. Having `Class` change what it returns based on what kind of expression the call to it is in is not a good direction to go for a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a way but it seems there isn't.

Comment: @user3289949 there really is a way, you just need to override `.toString`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: That's why I said `"(reasonably)"`. A change of approach is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: I can't disagree with that. What OP is doing sounds unreasonable.